# Get time from a text field in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I made an app for android that does certain calculations based on a time that is entered. I created a text field that has the input type of time. How would I access this information. Preferably I would like to access the total time entered in seconds however if I could find the number of hours, minutes, and seconds I could easily figure it out. I can't find a method for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is this something you need? i Wrote you something...

```
public static Calendar cal;
public static Date date;
private static SimpleDateFormat SimpleDateFormat;
private static SimpleDateFormat printFormat;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    cal =  new GregorianCalendar();
    date =  new Date();
    date = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(date);

    SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy.");       
    String datum = SimpleDateFormat.format(date);       
    System.out.println("Date: " + datum);

    printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("Time - Now: " + printFormat.format(date));


    int minute= date.getMinutes();
    int hour = date.getHours();
    int sec = date.getSeconds();

    StringBuilder time =  new StringBuilder();
    time.append(hour + " ");
    time.append(minute + " ");
    time.append(sec + " ");
    System.out.println("Time: " + time);

    //time in sec
    timeInSec(minute, hour, sec);
}

private static void timeInSec(int minute, int hour, int sec) {
    int seconds = 0;
    if (hour > 0) {
        seconds += (hour * 60 *60);
    }
    if (minute > 0) {
        seconds += minute*60;
    }
    if (sec > 0) {
        seconds += sec;
    }
    System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + seconds );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an EditText, you can use editText.getText().toString to get your input String.

To parse your input into a date, use DateFormat class.

It depends on how do you want to handle the text input.